# NextJS not rendering props in localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with a custom hook/function in nextJS, where I getData from firebase, and then map out the array.
It is supposed to be large black squares showing (as in picture), but it's empty beneath the

tag beneath CASES. See pic 2.
When I consol log it, the arrays are not showing.

It was showing in the localhost live server, but something happened that caused this bug. However, when I go into the code, especially the parent page, and do something like delete a random blank line, then everything pops forth.

I have also noticed how the consol logs (consol.log(nameOfArray)) sometimes show an empty array but more times show an array - but it doesn't render into the browser.
I get no error messages, either those that comes sometimes when a module can't read code (for example cannot map an empty state).

I am using firefox but I have doublechecked on chrome. Same problem.
I am using NextJS 13.0 with styled-components, as well as a custom hook to fetch data from firebase since getStaticProps/Paths/Serversideprops doesn't seem to work with firebase. Again: this have worked until 12 hours ago.
I have small edits in the next.config, which is mainly compiler to styledComponents and reactStrictMode. I have deleted node_modules and re-installed them. I have also tried to skip importing getData and have it directly in casespage: no show.

Are there perhaps too many modules? I would think so, but at the same time I have the same trouble with another page who doesn't have any children or parent modules, it doesn't show either until I fiddle around in VSC.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wV23.png)

Here is the structure of the code:

**index

homepage

casespage (getData happens here, sends data as props to->) 

showcases (passing props further to:)


featured (in here, the array is filtered and then passed as a prop to)

casefItem**

index is in pages, the rest are in components/homepage
getData (async export function) is in components/api/cases 
[first page calling getData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aN2f.png)
[secodn module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAdFY.png)
[third module: also filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPL6Q.png)
[last child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWk5j.png)
[getData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGnsD.png)

This is in dev mode, i.e. when I use npm run dev.

[how it should be / how it is when I go into the VSC and "edit"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeMwY.png)

[what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK6iP.png)

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I tried to do this but something with uploading the code didn't want to work. :/